# Why is the ternary operator returning 0?

Tags: c++, c++11, conditional-operator

Why does the following code have '0' as output?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main() {
    int max = 5;
    std::cout << (false) ? "impossible" : std::to_string(max);
}
```

Comment: Look at [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Because `false` is printed as `0`. The statement is equivalent to `(std::cout << false) ? "impossible" : std::to_string(max);`. You probably want `std::cout << (false ? "impossible" : std::to_string(max));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement

```
std::cout << false ? "impossible" : std::to_string(max);
```

is equivalent to

```
(std::cout << false) ? "impossible" : std::to_string(max);
```

because `<<` has higher precedence than `?:` and `false` is printed as `0`.

You probably expected this

```
std::cout << (false ? "impossible" : std::to_string(max));
```

You should read [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) to avoid such surprises.

Comment: Operator precidence: `*` binds tighter than `+`, `.` and `->` is tighter than both, assignment is very loose, and everything else just use `()`.

Comment: to put short: "When in doubt, use parenthesis."

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie That's not enough, as this question shows that it's even unclear when you should be in doubt :-)

Comment: @BartoszKP Anywhere it isn't just *,/, +,- and =, because algebra is the  lesser common denominator